# How to aggregate columns dynamically in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, aggregate-functions

I want to calculate percentage of non-missing value `pct_<original_name>_valid` for each of the input columns. In this example there are only 2 columns, so it's easy to manually script the code below. But when there are 30+ columns, I don't want to do this manually. Is it even possible to do this dynamically? (for instance, taking a list of column names as an input)

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

d = [{'name': 'Alice', 'age': 1}, {'name': 'Bae', 'age': None}]
df = spark.createDataFrame(d)

df.withColumn('name_valid', F.when(col("name").isNotNull(),1).otherwise(0))\
.withColumn('age_valid', F.when(col("age").isNotNull(),1).otherwise(0))\
.agg(
    (100.0*F.sum(col("name_valid"))/F.count(F.lit(1))).alias("pct_name_valid"),
    (100.0*F.sum(col("age_valid"))/F.count(F.lit(1))).alias("pct_age_valid")
)\
.show()
```

Here is the result:

```
+--------------+-------------+
|pct_name_valid|pct_age_valid|
+--------------+-------------+
|         100.0|         50.0|
+--------------+-------------+
```

As mentioned earlier, I don't want to manually do this for all 30+ columns. Is there any way I can do like:

```
my_output = calculate_non_missing_percentage(df, my_columns = ["name", "age", "gender", "school", "color"])
```

Comment: I have updated my answer. It will answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I find the null values dynamically in my code is in this way:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import isnan, when, count

total_count = df.count()
null_values = df.select(
    [(count(when(isnan(c), c)) / total_count).alias(c) for c in df.columns]
)

# Another way to do it is (ref neobot)
null_values = df.select(
    [(sum(when(isnull(c), 1).otherwise(0)) / total_count).alias(c) for c in df.columns]
)
```

The trick is in creating the list before hand. You list the functions you want to apply on the columns and then pass the list to select.

I use this to count distinct values in my data:

`df.agg(*(countDistinct(col(c)).alias(c) for c in df.columns)`
(given the columns are string columns, didn't put that condition here)

Comment: I changed the last line of the code block to this and it works: `null_values = df.select([(sum(when(isnull(c), 1).otherwise(0))/total_count).alias(c) for c in df.columns])`

Comment: Please upvote/select if the answer was helpful. I'll add your method to the answer as well.

Answer (score 5):

You can dynamically aggregate on your columns using their name.

```py
cols = df.columns

# transform null values in 0, else 1
df = df.select(
    *(
        F.when(
            F.col(col).isNull(),
            0
        ).otherwise(1).alias(col)
        for col
        in cols
    )
)

# percentage of non-missing value
df = df.agg(
    *(
        (F.sum(col)/F.count(col)).alias('{}_ratio'.format(col))
        for col
        in cols
    )
)

df.show()                                                                                                       
+---------+----------+
|age_ratio|name_ratio|
+---------+----------+
|      0.5|       1.0|
+---------+----------+
```